# Merge the [android-lollipop] and [android-5.0-lollipop] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[android-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-lollipop) is the same as [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop), but [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop) a) uses the naming scheme that every other Android version tag has uses, and b) has been around longer.

Can the [android-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-lollipop) tag be merged & synonymized into [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop)?