# Merge [android-marshmallow] and [android-m] into [android-6.0-marshmallow]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It's [that time of year again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278018/merge-the-android-lollipop-and-android-5-0-lollipop-tags)... Google recently unveiled the name for the latest version of Android, and we're left with three individual tags. As has been the naming precedent for many years, the "official" tag should be [android-6.0-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0-marshmallow). Can [android-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-m) and [android-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-marshmallow) please be merged into [android-6.0-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0-marshmallow)?

Comment: Just merge them into [android] to get it over with.  Why on Earth would anybody developing for Android not want to know about it?

Comment: Now I really want some marshmallows...

Comment: @HansPassant You'd (hopefully) want to know, but it's the same boat as say C# 6.0 -- new APIs, something may not work the same as it did on a previous version... a bug in your app that shows up only on Marshmallow -- that kind of stuff.