# Retag all [lollipop]s to [android-5.0-lollipop]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There is a tag [lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) with 142 questions. As far as I can see, *all of them* are about Android Lollipop, which has it's own tag [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop).

So I tried to simply suggest it as a synonym, but that failed because:

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

I cannot see why [lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) should not be a synonym of (or merged into) [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop), since I couldn't identify any other use for that tag.

---

**Conclusion from comments**

The best option seems to be to retag all [lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) questions to [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop) (or [android-5.1.1-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.1.1-lollipop) if they're specifically about 5.1), and effectively remove the [lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) tag. This allows [lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) to be reused sometime in future if there will be some other technology named "lollipop".

Comment: Um... there's also an `android-5.1.1-lollipop` tag... seems rather specific...

Comment: @JonClements I don't know why that tag even exists, should be `android-5.1-lollipop` IMO, 5.1.1 is indeed a quite specific version, and I can't think of anything special about 5.1.1

Comment: So `lollipop` could really be more than one tag - either 5.0 or 5.1? And should 5.1.1 really be 5.1? How deep does this rabbit hole go Alice? :p

Comment: @JonClements well, 5.0 is the main lollipop version, 5.1 is just an API update. The tag wiki for 5.1.1 is about the 5.1 version (not 5.1.1 specifically), so maybe 5.1.1 should be renamed to 5.1?

Comment: That depends what API changes there were between 5.1 and 5.1.1... Might make a real difference.

Comment: @Moshe there were no API changes from 5.1 and 5.1.1, it's both API level 22. Version 5.1.1 is just an OS bugfix update.

Comment: if lollipop can mean either 5.1 or 5.0 (or possibly 5.2 some day?), I'm not sure if synonym is the way to go. Based on information on [this similar request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278018/merge-the-android-lollipop-and-android-5-0-lollipop-tags?rq=1) about naming scheme, and since there aren't that many of lollipop-tagged questions, should current lollipop questions just be retagged?

Comment: @eis There won't be a 5.2, because 6.0 already exists. I know that doesn't always follow, but Android versions aren't "branched" in that way, and the "API level" increases chronologically, so Lollipop is level 21 and 22, Marshmallow is level 23. So level 24 will either be 6.1 or 7.0, Marshmallow or "N". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Comment: Ok. My question is still valid, should we just retag the lollipop questions?

Comment: @eis That would be the other option: retag all and burninate the `lollipop` tag.

Comment: Since we cannot know whether a product called `lollipop` could ever exist in the vastness of this universe it would probably make sense to retag all android lollipop questions to android-5.0-lollipop. In my humble opinion it doesn't make much sense to use an ambiguous and unspecific name like that at all, therefor making it a synonym doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @konqi what if I have a question about how to programatically find the most efficient way to lick a lollipop?

Comment: @Braiam I'd flag that question as *too broad*. There are too many different types of lollipops and consumption styles. So there would be 'either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format'. Although the lollipop is a concrete problem the question for how to programatically consume it is more suited for the programmers community, after all you're asking for an algorithm. But in case you get stuck licking your lollipop please post what you've got so far and we might be able to help with that and clean up the mess.